# Power Query From Table/Range

Tags: excel, powerquery

If I select a cell in a range of data in an Excel sheet, I can see "From Table/Range" button active under "Get & Transform Data" group under 'Data' tab. But if I convert that range into an Excel Table, then "From Table/Range" button becomes inactive. Then in that case, I have no option but to select a Blank Query and use Excel.CurrentWorkbook function. What could be the possible reason for this strange behavior? I am using latest version of Office365.

Comment: MS Professional Plus 2016, and I thought all 2016s, you should be able to load an Excel table using from table. Have you googled whether this is a known bug? How are you converting to an Excel table?

Comment: It's a known bug in the Insider build. Microsoft is aware of it.

Comment: Thanks teylyn for this... keeping fingers crossed.